# Spring JUnit test autowired variable in tested class

Tags: java, spring, junit, dependency-injection

I'd like to test a class which has a resource injected via @Autowired annotation.

```
class TestedClass{
  @Autowired
  private MyResource resource
  ...
}
```

How can I make this injection to work without modifying the tested class? The injection works fine in the test class, but not in the tested class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations= "classpath*:/bean-definition.xml")
  public class TestedClassTest {
  TestedClass instance;

  //This works
  @Autowired
  private MyResource resource

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    instance = new TestedClass();
  }
...
}
```

So the problem is probably how to pass the context to the tested class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inject TestedClass don't create with `new()`, I assume its a bean. Or inject myResource into testedClass using setter or constructor.

Comment: No tested class is not a bean, it only uses injected resource. Does it make sense? Or does it have to be a bean as well? I know I can do it via setter or constructor, but I think there must be some way to do it without modifying the code.

Comment: how when the app is deployed does testedclass get instantiated as if it is not injected, my resource will not be set. So it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok. So I created a ```Component``` of the tested class and now it works. Thanks